# trigger to count the number of related records

Tags: after-trigger

I have a requirement to count the number of candidates looking upto a Test Center object. The field "No of Candidates" on the Test Center object should calculate the number of candidates associated.
I wrote an After trigger but it's not updating the field:

```
trigger candidateTrigger on Candidate__c (after insert, after update, after delete) {
    candidateTriggerHandler.calcNoOfCandidates(Trigger.isDelete ? Trigger.old : Trigger.new);
}
```

---

```
public class candidateTriggerHandler {

    public static void calcNoOfCandidates(List<Candidate__c> candList) {
        Set <ID> TestCenters = New Set <ID>();
        for (Candidate__c can : candList) {
            if (can.Test_Center__r.ID != NULL) {
                TestCenters.add(can.Test_Center__r.ID);
            }
        }
        Map<Id, List<Candidate__c>> mapTestCntrToCand = New Map<Id, List<Candidate__c>>();

        for (Test_Center__c tc : [
                SELECT ID, No_of_Candidates__c, (SELECT Id FROM Candidates__r)
                FROM Test_Center__c
                WHERE Id IN :TestCenters
        ]) {
            mapTestCntrToCand.put(tc.Id, tc.Candidates__r);
        }

        for (Candidate__c can : candList) {
            if (mapTestCntrToCand.containsKey(can.Test_Center__r.ID)) {
                Integer noOfCands = 0;
                for (Candidate__c c : mapTestCntrToCand. get (can.Test_Center__r.ID)) {
                    noOfCands++;

                }
                can.Test_Center__r.No_of_Candidates__c = noOfCands;

            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are these related as Master Detail or a lookup field data type?

Comment: Why would it update the field? You're in an `after` trigger and you are not performing a dml `update`.

Comment: Infact, I tried this as well. It's still not working:

        
        List<Test_Center__c> testCntrsToUpdt = [SELECT ID, No_of_Candidates__c , (SELECT Id FROM Candidates__r) 
                               FROM Test_Center__c WHERE Id IN:TestCenters];
        List<Test_Center__c> testCntrsToUpdt1 = New List<Test_Center__c>();
        
        for(Test_Center__c tc:testCntrsToUpdt){
            tc.No_of_Candidates__c = tc.Candidates__r.size();
            testCntrsToUpdt1.add(tc);
        }
        update testCntrsToUpdt1;

Answer (score 3):

```
for (Candidate__c can : candList) {
    if (can.Test_Center__r.ID != NULL) {
        TestCenters.add(can.Test_Center__r.ID);
    }
}
```

`Test_Center__r.ID` will **always** be null, because related objects are not loaded in `Trigger.new`/`Trigger.old`. You can fix this with:

```
for (Candidate__c can : candList) {
    TestCenters.add(can.Test_Center__c);
}
TestCenters.remove(null); // Remove nulls afterwards
```

Ditto for all the other places where you're using `__r.Id` instead of just `__c`.

Also, this method you're using is inefficient; just use an aggregate query:

```
// Get all Test Center Ids, as before, then:
Map<Id, AggregateResult> totals = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([
  SELECT COUNT(ID) sum, Test_Center__c Id
  FROM Candidate__c
  WHERE Test_Center__c = :TestCenters
  GROUP BY Test_Center__c;
]);
Test_Center__c[] updates = new Test_Center__c[0];
for(Id TestCenterId: TestCenters) {
  updates.add(
    new Test_Center__c(
      Id=TestCenterId, 
      No_of_Candidates__c=(Decimal)totals.get(TestCenterId)?.get('sum')
    )
  );
}
update updates;
```